# Dynamically get some data and insert it into a div (wordpress related)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

I have a challenge with a wordpress theme I'm developing, but I think what I'm after is really just a general php/JS solution, nothing Wordpress specific.

So I have the below code with pulls in the thumbnail and description for an array of images I have uploaded. What I'd like to do is when a user clicks on the link the description and caption associated with that image is displayed in a div elsewhere on the page.

My issue is that so far the only way I can think of to do that is to set a javascript variable within my php foreach statement, but the problem with that is that this overwrites the variable value each time (as I can't change the variable name) so by the end of it all I don't have a different JS variable for each image, I just have one with the details from the last image in the array.

I know AJAX might be one way forward, but I know pretty much nothing about it. If anyone can help point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

```
<?php 
        $gallery_images = get_custom_field('galleryImages:to_array');
        foreach ($gallery_images as $galleryID) {
            $description = $attachment->post_content;                               //get image description
            $caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;                                   //get image caption
            ?>
                <a href="[JS/AJAX to load this items description and caption into target div]">link</a>
            <?php
        }


?>

<div id="targetDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going about this the wrong way, personally. Using AJAX to interact with a WordPress site seems like overkill for the simple ability of showing some peripheral information about an image.

What I would do is have WordPress spit out the image, along with the caption info when the page is initially downloaded, but hide the caption info and then use client-side JavaScript to show/hide it when it's needed.

```
<?php

    $button_html = "";
    $caption_html = "";

    $gallery_images = get_custom_field('galleryImages:to_array');

    $gallery_images_count = 0;

    foreach ($gallery_images as $galleryID) {

        $description = $attachment->post_content; //get image description
        $caption = $attachment->post_excerpt; //get image caption

        $button_html .= '<div id="caption-button-' . $gallery_images_count . '" class="show-caption-button">Show Caption</div>';

        $caption_html .= '<div id="caption-' . $gallery_images_count . '" style="display:none;">' . $caption . '</div>';

        $gallery_images_count++;

    }

    echo '<div id="buttonDiv">' . $button_html . '</div>';
    echo '<div id="targetDiv">' . $caption_html . '</div>';

?>
```

Then the JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$('.show-caption-button').click(function(){

    var caption_id = $(this).prop('id').substring(15);

    $('#caption-'+caption_id).eq(0).toggle();

});
```

It's hard to test without setting up a WordPress myself, but essentially what we're doing is adding caption divs with numbered id's to a string variable in PHP as we're looping through our images. Then, at the end of the loop, we echo that out to the page.

In JavaScript/jQuery, we're grabbing the corresponding id of the caption button and using it to toggle the relevant caption further down in the page.

Comment: Interesting. The only outstanding issue is that I have the same target div for all of the captions, so that can't be included within my foreach...

Comment: Thanks for updating, it's not working for me yet - do you have an unclosed </php tag in there that shouldn't be?

Comment: thanks again - still seems to be a problem. When I try to render the page I get the following error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_INC in /path/to/page.php on line 70

Line 70 is: "gallery_images_count++;"

Comment: @Kev Ok, you're going to have to use some PHP common sense here... There was a typo in the variable we're trying to increment (no dollar sign in front of it). Have changed it now.

Comment: Sorry, I should be more observant. There was also a missing 's' on $gallery_image_count when you call it within the $button_html variable. Thanks for your help, I think this has given me enough to get it all working nicely :)

Comment: @Kev Glad it's been helpful. Obviously you'll want to tweak with your own structure but this is the general gist of what I would do.